# AD B2C integration with Flutter (Android) app

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to integrate ad b2c to a Flutter app using aad_b2c_webview library (https://pub.dev/documentation/aad_b2c_webview/latest/). The problem is that I am getting "ERR: UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" and the actual error is aadb2c90006 - "The redirect URI provided in the request is not registered for the client id".

I would appreciate if someone can show the right direction. Below are the steps I've done.

1. Created a tenant in Azure Portal
2. Registered the app
3. Added redirect URI for Android which has the following structure: msauth://com.companyname.appname/my-hash-code
4. Added the below activity block in my AndroidManifest.xml
5. Implemented the sample for aad_b2c_webview

```
<activity
    android:exported="true"
    android:name="com.microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="msauth"
            android:host="com.companyname.appname"
            android:path="/my-hash-code" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**UPDATE**

1. Removed the above XML from AndroidManifest.xml
2. Added the following redirect URI (under 'Mobile and desktop applications): com.example.appname://oauth/redirect

After this I could login, but the redirection back to app is failing with the following error message:

"The web page at com.example.appname://oauth/redirect?code=the-real-code could not be loaded because net:: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME"

Any advise is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Refer the sample to develop Flutter package aad_b2c_webview which embeds AAD user flow/custom policy within a mobile app - https://github.com/microsoft/aad_b2c_webview/tree/main

Comment: @ShwetaM That's exactly what I did - "I am trying to integrate ad b2c to a Flutter app using aad_b2c_webview library". Would be nice to hear less generic answers.